# Stripe -- after confirmCardPayment, how to attach the new card to the customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using a `setupIntent` to save a card to a customer for future use. I pass the client_secret from the `setupIntent` to the `confirmCardSetup` in js.

Later, I create a `paymentIntent` with that card. If it is declined and the status is `requires_payment_method` then I email the customer and give them a form to enter a new card, and subit that using `confirmCardPayment` in js. This works well and the charge succeeds (or becomes `requires_capture`).

How do I then attach that new payment method to the customer? If I do nothing, then their old saved card is still their primary payment method.

I only want to keep one card on file for each customer. I know I can detach the old card and then attach the new one, but then it will not have been done using a `setupIntent`, which is apparently more appropriate if I'm going to be charging the card in the future off session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also save a card for future use during a payment using `setup_future_usage=off_session` by following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment). The payment method will be automatically attached to the customer provided on the Payment Intent.

Your existing flow can be used, you'd just extend it by:

1. Prior to confirming the Payment Intent again with the new payment details, update it to set the `setup_future_usage` option.
2. After the payment succeeds, detach the old payment method like you mentioned and, if needed, update your internal reference to the payment method to use for that customer to be the new payment method id from the Payment Intent.

Comment: The payment method has to be attached to the stripe customer. The method confirmCardPayment successfully authorizes and attaches the new card to that payment intent, but it doesn't do what the original confirmCardSetup does, which is attach it to the customer.

Comment: Oh are you saying that setting setup_future_usage when submitting the confirmCardPayment will attach it to the customer? I'm gonna try that.

Comment: Yes, setup_future_usage automatically attach the card to the Customer.